# How do I create a dynamic key for a key/value pair in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just now my code is:

```
data = {'field_name':"some value",'name':$(this).val()};
```

However, I'd like to change the name key so it is dynamic, e.g something like:

```
var name = $(this).attr('id');
data = {'field_name':"some value",name:$(this).val()};
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You want properties, see [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 2):

To do this use the indexer syntax

```
var data = { 'field_name': "some value" };
data[name] = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not required for this:

```
data = {'field_name':"some value"};
data[this.id] = this.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var val = data.name;
delete data.name;
data[name] = val; //name is the identifier here
```